# Unity 2.0 for shared application configuration possible?

Tags: configuration, unity-container

I'm struggling with trying to create a shared configuration file for a web project and 2 dll projects.  From what I can tell  [StructedMap](http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2009/07/13/how-we-handle-application-configuration/) can be used for configuration settings.  Anyone successfully use Unity 2.0 to do the same?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? StructureMap is a DI container. It's a tool to compose loosely coupled applications. It has nothing to do with storing/reusing settings across multiple projects. Unity is another DI container with similar capabilities as StructureMap. Do you want to know what to do to inject settings into your classes using Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a custom configuration.  Phil Hack has a great tutorial [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx).